# Ubuntu: Rename multiple files in different directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rename

I need to rename files which are in this structure:

```
Dir1
--file1
--file2
--  ... 
Dir2
--file1
--file2
--  ... 
... 
Dir62
--file1101
--file1102
--  ...
```

The new names would be 1_01,1_02 in 1 dir and 2_01,2_02 in 2nd dir and so on...

is there a way to do it in a single go...

Currently, I am using:

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "10_$n.png"; done
```

Which work in 1 dir at a time...

Any better way, please?

Comment: That's mad. Why would you do that? The files will end up with arbitrary names consisting of a prefix that depends on the sort order of `ls` and is unrelated to the name of the directory containing the file and a suffix which loses any relationship to its original name.

Comment: So if the first directory listed is `Dir7` and the first file in there is `file8` it will end up as `Dir7/1_01`...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have to rename these files for machine learning. for that, their name should be in a certain format. the order of files doesn't matter until they stay in their own directories...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this command, it will use **GNU Parallel** to start a new `bash`shell in each of the directories in parallel, and run `ls` in each one in parallel independently:

```
parallel --dry-run -k 'cd {} && ls' ::: */
```

**Sample Output**

```
cd Dir01/ && ls
cd Dir02/ && ls
cd Dir78/ && ls
```

If you remove the `--dry-run` it will do it for real.

So, instead of running `ls`, let's now look at using the `rename` command in each of the directories. The following will rename all the files in a directory with sequentially increasing numbers (`$N`):

```
rename --dry-run '$_=$N' *
```

**Sample Output**

```
'file87' would be renamed to '1'
'file88' would be renamed to '2'
'file89' would be renamed to '3'
'fred' would be renamed to '4'
```

---

All the foregoing suggests the command you want would be:

```
parallel --dry-run -k 'cd {} && rename --dry-run "s/.*/{#}_\$N/" *' ::: */
```

You can run it as it is and it will just show you what it is going to do, without actually doing anything.

If you like the look of that, remove the first `--dry-run` and run it again and it will actually go into each subdirectory and do a dry-run of the rename, again without actually changing anything.

If you still like the look of the command, make a small copy of your files somewhere in a temporary directory and try removing both the `--dry-run` parameters ands if it lives up to your needs.

Comment: It works with dry-run but an error in real. - 
`"Global symbol "$N" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $N"?) at (user-supplied code). "`

I tried to initialize $N some value, also created it as an environment variable, but still didn't work...

What is $N?

Comment: If you have a look in the manpage for `rename` you will see `$N` is just a sequentially increasing number that increases for each file. Try it like the second example I gave. There are several `rename` programs out there so you could potentially have a different one - the one I am using is a Perl script, so check if yours is too... `file $(which rename)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 -d ./*/ | cat -n | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "%" | while read dirnum dirname; do { ls "${dirname}" | cat -n | while read filenum filename; do { mv -v "${dirname}${filename}" "${dirnum}_${filenum}.png"; }; done }; done'
```

We create a directory structure with mkdir and touch:

```
mkdir Dir{1,2,3,4,5}
touch Dir{1,2,3,4,5}/file{1,2,3}
```

Which gives the result:

```
1_1.png
1_2.png
1_3.png
2_1.png
2_2.png
2_3.png
3_1.png
3_2.png
3_3.png
4_1.png
4_2.png
4_3.png
5_1.png
5_2.png
5_3.png
```

Comment: It does work to some extent. It renamed all files - but, moved all file from subdirectories to the main directory - **I ended up having 70k files in 1 main directory.**